# Need help to run my first struts2 application... error is resource is not available

Tags: xml, jsp, struts2

Please tell me what is causing the error ("resource is not available") in my first Struts2 application coding and how to fix it.

***STRUTS.XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts  
Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">  

<struts>

<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="getdata" class="com.hardik.actions.TutorialAction">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>`enter code here`
        <result name="failure">/errror.jsp</result>

    </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

**WEB.XML FILE CONTENT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>struts2Started</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>



  <filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

***TUTORIAL ACTION CLASS***

```
public class TutorialAction {

    public String execute()
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
        return "success";
    }

}
```

1. I have included all jars in lib folder and in they are in build path
2. I am using struts-2.3.16.1
3. I am trying to execute this url

Comment: Do you actually have that "enter code here" in struts.xml or is that a copy and paste error?

Comment: Define "included all jars".

Answer (score 0):

You can put your struts.xml inside the classes folder. Just Make one folder named as classes inside WEB-INF directory and then check your action is calling or not.